# Is every finite consistent extension of ZFC and PA incomplete?

Tags: model-theory

Let $T$ denote either the theory $ZFC$ or $PA$. Suppose we have a finite set $S$ of sentences which are consistent with $T$. Is the deductive closure of $T \cup S$ incomplete?

Comment: *Comment since I think this is a duplicate:* yes, this follows immediately from the stronger version of the first incompleteness theorem: any consistent recursively axiomatizable theory extending ZFC or PA (or indeed merely interpreting Q) is incomplete. This is *not* quite what Godel initially proved, and doesn't follow from his original argument; it requires [Rosser's trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rosser%27s_trick) or the later proof via recursively inseparable sets (see also [this MO thread](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/72062/what-are-some-proofs-of-godels-theorem-which-are-)).

Comment: @Noah: doesn't the argument via reduction to the halting problem get us this immediately or am I missing a subtlety in the argument?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Not immediately. By the low basis theorem, every computably axiomatizable theory - such as ZFC - has complete consistent extensions much weaker than the halting problem. The issue is that an unsound extension might prove false things about the halting problem. Recursive inseparability exactly addresses the (correct) intuition that this shouldn't be able to really get us all the way down to computability, i.e., even "fake" halting problems should be non-computable.

Comment: (A bit more transparently: if $T$ is a putative complete consistent computable extension of - say - $\mathsf{ZFC}$, then consider the set $H_T$ of standard natural numbers $n$ such that $T\vdash\Phi_n(n)\downarrow$. This certainly *contains* the true halting problem $H=\{n:\Phi_n(n)\downarrow\}$, but it might overshoot it. Fortunately, this isn't a problem since $H_T$ must also be disjoint from the set $J:=\{m:\mathsf{ZFC}\vdash\Phi_n(n)\uparrow\}$, and $(H,J)$ is a recursively inseparable pair so we get a contradiction.)

Comment: @Noah: oh, I think I understand. The extension could be something like $PA + \neg \text{Con}(PA)$, which (assuming that PA is actually consistent) has a false belief about whether the Turing machine searching for a proof of an inconsistency in PA halts?